# ios Facebook login button delegate/callback

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I was just wondering how I can popup a loading screen blocker once the user has entered a username and password on ios Facebook connect dialog and after clicking the login button.  I mean, where can I find the delegate that handles the action or callback upon clicking of login button.